# how to paste to a hidden sheet in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Range("A1:Z9").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

this code fails if Sheet2 is hidden. is there any way around it?

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:Z9").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z9").Value`.

Comment: And the obligatory link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1